# Execute purely anonymous function in PHP

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

What's the suggested way to execute an anonymous function in PHP similar to how Javascript provides this possibility?

Javascript:

```
(function(){ console.log('Hello!'); })();
```

Trying the same in PHP yields a syntax error for the parameters opening bracket. I've found a way around this problem by "mis-using" call_user_func():

PHP:

```
call_user_func(function(){ echo "Hello!"; });
```

But the [PHP documentation](http://de.php.net/call_user_func) (**update:** the *German* version of the docs) explicitly says the first parameter to call_user_func() should be a string... So I'm not sure if my solution is supposed to work correct (however, it does for the moment).

The purpose behind this solution - similar to the reason why you would do it the same way in JavaScript - is to not pollute the global namespace for some added functionality. This script is auto-prepended for all scripts on the whole server and should be hidden wrt global namespace and global scope. It's not meant to be invisible - just keep symbols out of the namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the PHP documentation explicitly says the first parameter to
>   call_user_func() should be a string

No it doesn't.

> `mixed call_user_func ( callable $callback [, mixed $parameter [, mixed $... ]] )`

The first parameter is of type `callable`, so your code is perfectly valid :)

Comment: Ah this sheds light into the darkness: The German version of the documentation is not up-to-date and still shows "string" as the type... Damn. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is appropriate. The first argument to `call_user_func` should be a [callable](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), a type  which includes closures.